# Visual Studio Reference Manager - Assembly Framework vs. COM Type Library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference

Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between adding a reference in the `Reference Manager` of Visual Studio as an "assembly framework" vs. adding it as a "COM type library"? I realize that COM Type libraries are not available for all references.

For example: If I want to work with the Microsoft Speech API, I can use it as an "assembly framework":

[image: Reference as an Assembly Framework]

Or I can use it as a "COM Type Library":

[image: Reference as a COM Type Library]

I am not looking to implement anything with the Microsoft Speech API. This was taken just as an example to elaborate what I am asking.

What is the difference between using either of these options?

Are they referring to the same libraries? I see the version number is different on the right pane in the two screenshots.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a slightly archeological view, those are the apis that programmers used before .NET became available.  In this case for SAPI, the Speech API which has been around since ~1995.  The COM wrapper for it is not exactly obsolete, you still use it when you write code in, say, C++ or a scripting language like Javascript.

Microsoft decided to create a more .NET-centric wrapper for it.  Fair call, the COM wrapper does not do a great job when you want to listen to events.  Not the only example, other good ones are System.Management (wraps WMI), System.Messaging (wraps MQ), System.Data.OleDb (wraps ADO), System.DirectoryServices (wraps AD).

There is no compelling reason to favor the COM wrapper, System.Speech was done pretty well and is complete.  In general there is a strong push inside Microsoft to hide COM, programming it can be fairly unpleasant, especially if it is not the Automation subset.  There's fairly little joy in programming core apis like WASAPI or DirectX directly.

The most complete wrapping job is probably Univeral Windows (aka WinRT, aka Store apps, aka Modern UI, aka UWP), thoroughly modern and thoroughly COM at its core.  Hidden very well, the "language projection" is a pretty neat trick.  Otherwise the basic way you can get a Javascript app to talk to a C++ component directly.  And the basic reason why error reporting is so lousy :)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between using either of these options?

They are completely different platforms.  COM has existed for a lot longer and was used to provide common functionality to Windows applications before .NET was developed.  It's considered "legacy" now, and is more difficult to comsume.

The differences between the two are too numerous for this forum, but they are like comparing apps for Android and iOS - they are meant for consumption by two different clients.  Some apps exist for both, but many exist for one or the other.  Some libraries expose methods to both; some only one or the other.

If you are referencing a library from a .NET application you will ALWAYS want to reference the .NET assembly, except in very rare circumstances (for example, if the COM library has different functionality that the assembly does not).

> Are they referring to the same libraries?

Not directly - there may be *wrappers* for one or the other that use the same code underneath, but at the interop level they are not the same.

Comment: So where are the COM objects listed in the `Reference Manager` located on a workstation? I believe the items listed in the "assembly framework" section comes from the GAC. In the `Microsoft Speech API` example, does the COM type library come from `%windir%\System32\Speech\Common\sapi.dll`?

Comment: Or is it the other way around where the COM types in Reference Manager are taken from the GAC?

Comment: COM libraries are "registered" with the system and can be in virtually any location.  All of that linkage is stored in the registry.  There's not a simple way to determine the physical location of a COM library just by its name;  It takes some breadcrumb searching in the registry which is not pleasant.